# Example of an element in $\,\ell^q\!\smallsetminus \ell^p$, with $1< p<q$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\ell^p$ denote the set $\left\{ (x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N} : x_n\in\Bbb C, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p < \infty \right\}$, for $p\in (1,\infty)$.

I've already shown that if $1<p<q$ then $\ell^p\subset \ell^q$. Now I'm having troubles to find an element of $\ell^q\setminus \ell^p$ to conclude that $\ell^p\subsetneqq \ell^q$.

Can someone give me an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have it reversed in the title.

Comment: Oh, yes! Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n^{2/(p+q)}}
$$
Then
$$
a_n^p=\frac{1}{n^{2p/(p+q)}}>\frac{1}{n}\quad\text{and}\quad
a_n^q=\frac{1}{n^{2q/(p+q)}}=\frac{1}{n^{1+d}},
$$
where $d=\frac{q-p}{q+p}>0$. Thus
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^p_n=\infty\quad\text{while}\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^p_n<\infty
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Play around with series of the form

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a(\ln n)^b},$$

where $a,b>0.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\sum_{n\geq 1} n^{-a}$ is finite if and only if $a>1$.

(Additional exercise if you know some measure theory: $\int_0^1 x^{-a}\,\textrm{d}x$ is finite if and only if $a<1$. What does it say about $L^p[0,1]$ spaces? Both this exercise and you original question generalise to arbitrary measure spaces.)